# Vmware server vmnet module compilation problem

Tags: server, 64-bit, vmware-server

I am trying to install vmware server 2.02 on a Ubuntu server 10.04.3 64bit version following this guidde https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Server .  However when i execute the script it jus ends after an error

```
/home/cfpte/raducotescu-vmware-server-linux-2.6.3x-kernel-bb26dce/vmware-server-distrib/lib/modules/source/vmnet-only/driver.c:121: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
/home/cfpte/raducotescu-vmware-server-linux-2.6.3x-kernel-bb26dce/vmware-server-distrib/lib/modules/source/vmnet-only/driver.c:121: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘DEFINE_SEMAPHORE’
/home/cfpte/raducotescu-vmware-server-linux-2.6.3x-kernel-bb26dce/vmware-server-distrib/lib/modules/source/vmnet-only/driver.c:121: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
/home/cfpte/raducotescu-vmware-server-linux-2.6.3x-kernel-bb26dce/vmware-server-distrib/lib/modules/source/vmnet-only/filter.c:82: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘DEFINE_SEMAPHORE’
/home/cfpte/raducotescu-vmware-server-linux-2.6.3x-kernel-bb26dce/vmware-server-distrib/lib/modules/source/vmnet-only/filter.c:82: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
/home/cfpte/raducotescu-vmware-server-linux-2.6.3x-kernel-bb26dce/vmware-server-distrib/lib/modules/source/vmnet-only/filter.c: In function ‘VNetFilter_HandleUserCall’:
/home/cfpte/raducotescu-vmware-server-linux-2.6.3x-kernel-bb26dce/vmware-server-distrib/lib/modules/source/vmnet-only/filter.c:1089: error: ‘filterIoctlSem’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/cfpte/raducotescu-vmware-server-linux-2.6.3x-kernel-bb26dce/vmware-server-distrib/lib/modules/source/vmnet-only/filter.c:1089: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/home/cfpte/raducotescu-vmware-server-linux-2.6.3x-kernel-bb26dce/vmware-server-distrib/lib/modules/source/vmnet-only/filter.c:1089: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[2]: *** [/home/cfpte/raducotescu-vmware-server-linux-2.6.3x-kernel-bb26dce/vmware-server-distrib/lib/modules/source/vmnet-only/filter.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/cfpte/raducotescu-vmware-server-linux-2.6.3x-kernel-bb26dce/vmware-server-distrib/lib/modules/source/vmnet-only] Error 2
make: *** [vmnet.ko] Error 2
```

There is a problem compiling the vmnet module after it was patched. :(

Could somebody point in the rigth direction to fix this?

regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question was posted on [UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1769901) for your version of Ubuntu.

The recommendation was to follow the [link post](http://www.troublenow.org/316/installing-vmware-server-2-0-2-on-debian-6-0-1-x64/) - I've reproduced this below:

Download VMware-server-2.0.2-203138.x86_64.tar.gz from the vmware website and place it in /usr/src (you need to register on the VMware website before you can download)

Download my install file below and unpack it to `/usr/src`:

```
cd /usr/src
wget http://www.troublenow.org/files/vmware/vmware2.0.2-on-debian6.0.1.tar.gz
tar xvzf vmware2.0.2-on-debian6.0.1.tar.gz
cd /usr/src/vmware2
sh install-vmware-2.0.2.sh
```

This will unpack the files, patch them and start the vmware installation.
Answer all the questions during the vmware install and the installation should complete.

Now reboot the server and you should be ready to go.

The above vmware2.0.2-on-debian6.0.1.tar.gz file has the following content:

```
00-vmware-2.6.32_functional.diff
01-vmware-2.6.32_cosmetic.diff
02-vmnet-include.diff
install-vmware-2.0.2.sh
patch-vmware_2.6.3x.sh
vmware-config.pl.diff
```